# visual studio Cdialog that blocks execution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am working with c++ in visual studio. In our application, when the user clicks a button, a Cdialog box appears asking them to select certain information. We need to use that information in the next line of code. Is there a way to block execution until the dialog box has been quit out of? My current solution is to split up the method, and add an event listener to the 'ok' button that then calls the second method. This seems very hacky though.

So the current solution has this to setup the dialog box

```
if (m_InstanceNumber == NULL)
{
    m_InstanceNumber = new CInstanceNumberDlg(this);
    m_InstanceNumber->Create(IDD_INSTANCE_RANGE_DIALOG, this);
    m_InstanceNumber->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
else{
    m_InstanceNumber->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

*clarification, the code that i need to wait to execute is directly below that code. *

then there is an event listener which successfully calls:

```
void CSolidHoopsFrame::updateInstanceRange() {
TRACE1("%d",m_InstanceNumber->leftInstanceRange());
TRACE1("%d",m_InstanceNumber->rightInstanceRange());
TRACE("entered updateInstanceRange");
}
```

This successfully prints the updated values from the box. So it seems that splitting the methods will work, it just seems like the incorrect way to go about doing this. Ideally there would be a way to reformat the first section of code such that the next line wouldn't execute till the box closes

Comment: Can we see what you have tried in code?

Comment: You have created a modeless dialog. It seems like your requirement would be met with a modal dialog. It returns from your call to DoModal when the dialog OK button is clicked.